# Баг при получении координат через e.offsetX

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Хочу чтобы координаты определялись относительно моего контейнера, но при подставлении в формулу e.offsetX, каждый второй тик элемент отправляется на 0, 0.

```
item.style.left = e.offsetX - shiftX + "px";
item.style.top = e.offsetY - shiftY + "px";
```

Вот пример: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gNgRYw.
Есть подставить вместо e.offsetX/Y e.pageX/Y ничего не дергается, но и отсчет начинается с документа.
Брал отсюда https://learn.javascript.ru/drag-and-drop

Comment: Оно не нужно для drag-n-drop'а.

Comment: Мне нужно позже добавить коллизию, да и в целом - это не то что мне надо.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var elem = elementName.getBoundingClientRect(); //Расположение вашего контейнер
item.style.left = event.clientX - elem.left;
item.style.top = event.clientY - elem.top;
```